# Would this single coil latching relay circuit work?

Tags: diodes, relay, coil, latch

[image]

The goal is to switch it in one direction by the upper button and then the other by the lower button (momentary push).

If it would work, where should I place the protection diodes? Or is it enough if I place a 10 uF capacitor parallel to the coil?

Comment: It depends entirely on the chosen relay. If you picked one at random from a large box of relays with different types no, this would not work but there may be some that can work this way. (the luck of the draw).

Comment: <some circuit with unknown relay> *will this work*? That depends on the relay, find such a relay (asking for one here is off-topic) and study the **datasheet**. You're adding resistors, why? You want diodes for protection, why? (what needs protecting? If you switch with a transistor, yes a flyback diode is needed, but you're using pushbuttons, these don't care if you use a flyback diode or not). Instead of "making up your own thing" go search for **existing solutions**, like those proposed in a datasheet.

Comment: Sorry, I should've added that it's assumed that the relay has enough current flowing through it and it's a single coil latching relay. The resistors are added so if I push both puttons at the same time it doesn't create a short circuit.

Comment: If it's a single-coil latching relay then I don't see why it wouldn't work, *except* you need to make sure the relay gets enough current because of the resistors.

Comment: Thanks. So diodes are not needed?

Answer (score 0):

The single coil latching relay circuit should be as shown.

[image]

Interlocking the push button switches would prevent dual-supply short-circuit, should both switches be actuated simultaneously.

An RC snubber across the relay coil would suppress voltage transients during turn-off.